# How can I run a Python function that handles files in background?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I've been trying to run a file handling function in Python in a background thread using default threading library but the Chrome tab still waits for the api to finish the processing.
I've tried threading & multiprocessing with no luck

Here is a snippet:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('upload.html')
    else:
        file = request.files['file']
        path = os.getcwd() + '\\tempFilesAudio\\'
        if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'tempFilesAudio'):
            os.mkdir(os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'tempFilesAudio')
        if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'tempFilesTransciption'):
            os.mkdir(os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'tempFilesTransciption')
        file.save(path + secure_filename(file.filename))
        file_path = path + file.filename
        conv_path = convert(file_path)
        print('converted:{}'.format(conv_path))
        pr = r.Recogniser()
        # this is a thread
        Thread(target=pr.recognize(conv_path),daemon=True).start()
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: You need to explain yourself more clearly. What is you are trying to do exactly? To me it looks like you need a background running process, not a thread. And, post your code as well.

Comment: Re, "I've tried..." Probably nobody can help you if you don't _show_ what you tried. Put some code in the question, and explain what you thought it would do. Re, "...with no luck," What does that mean? Was there an error message? Put the error message in your question. Did it behave in some other way that you don't understand? Tell us what it did. Include samples of any logs or other output from your program that don't make sense to you.

Comment: ive updated the question with a snippet, sorry for the bad write up earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to do this

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# list of variables for Pool
args=[1, 2, 3, 4] 

# We want to execute 4 threads at time
pool = Pool(4)

# Executing multithread process, we execute one function by item on the list
# This is like:
    # functionName(args[0])
    # functionName(args[1])  
    # functionName(args[2])
    # functionName(args[3])
pool.map(functionName, args) 

# We wait for the processes to finish
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Is this correct?

If this is correct, also, you can use 'nohup' as Nano_developer told you, and execute your code without keep your session (This is the correct way), you need to do this from command line:

```
nohup python myFile.py
```

Comment: thanks for the direction! I used pool.apply_async to achieve the desired procedure.

Comment: @KushSingh : Implementing what you want with multiprocessing has a potential to mess-up your server. You are waiting for processing to finish anyway, so, you gain essentially nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If you wanna just run application in a background and you are working on linux you can e.g.

1. Run python script with `nohup` command. E.g. `nohup python3 myscript.py`
2. If your system uses `systemd` you can write a service that will execute you script. Then you can also make it auto run with system.
   More information:
   https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd

Comment: I have a flask website and when i call the api it calls an other function. I want to make that inner function run in the background

Comment: Ok, so threading should do the job. Could you paste how you implemented you function with threading?

Comment: @KushSingh : Edit your Q and add this info along some more clarifications. But I do not see how is this connected with crone tab as you mentioned.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience , i have added a snippet

Answer (score 0):

Now it is clear what you want.

To save your file without delays, your saving process must go to the threading.Thread(). Not recognizer, or even better, everything all together.

Also, you should look at the documentation of the *.save() method, it may support non-blocking way already. The trouble is, the way the data transfer is performed you will have a delay, at least on the client's side while data is POSTed to the server. Writing to the disk is here considerably smaller bottle neck.

What you may try is to write a separate function that receives the request object or the file object as an argument. In this function you put saving and all actions file-handling stuff. Then in your routed flask function you
start the daemon thread with that function as a target and passing in the request or file object as the argument. And return the redirect immediately after the thread is started. Do not forget to call Thread().start() method.

The question is, when does flask starts receiving a file. If it starts immediately before a route call, i.e. while constructing the request object, this will not work. You will have to find another way around it. But, in this case, I am sure flask already has some support for such things.

If this works, on the client's side, you will experience the same behaviour though. A browser will wait until the file is transfered and only then react to the redirect. To avoid this, you will need javascript and ajax stuff. This would be easiest if jquery is used. You can even implement a progress tracking so that the user can see how much of the file has been transfered, and when the process is complete, and at the same time, the user will be able to use the site.

Ow, last thing that just occurred to me. If you are experiencing a problem that another client cannot access the server while another is uploading a file, then you didn't start flask correctly and it has nothing to do with having async IO in your script or not.